# Generating PHP Thrift files on HBase Amazon EMR

Tags: php, hbase, thrift, amazon-emr

I installed Apache Thrift on a running HBase (v 0.92 which is provided by default by amazon) cluster (I followed the official tutorial), but when I arrive at the point where I need to generate the required php files (`thrift --gen php hbase.thrift`), I can't find the hbase.thrift file anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Hbase.thrift file from [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-server/src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift?view=markup).

Answer (score 0):

The hbase thrift idl (Hbase.thrift) is packaged with the hbase source and located in:

> src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift

Answer (score 0):

On AWS EMR, you can find the hbase1.thrift and hbase2.thrift with the follow way:

```
[hadoop@ip-10-232-13-248 ~]$ sudo find / -name thrift
/usr/lib/hbase/include/thrift
/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-webapps/thrift
[hadoop@ip-10-232-13-248 ~]$ cd /usr/lib/hbase/include/thrift
[hadoop@ip-10-232-13-248 thrift]$ ls
hbase1.thrift  hbase2.thrift
```